# Swagger artifact is in external libraries but cannot be seen by IntellIJ

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, swagger, artifact

I'm trying to integrate swagger into my Playframework Scala project.

`"com.iheart" %% "play-swagger" % "0.7.5"`,
  `"org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "2.2.0"` is already in my build.sbt and can be resolved but in the plugins.sbt when i add `addSbtPlugin("com.iheart" %% "sbt-play-swagger" % "0.7.5")` it says `com.iheart` is unknown artifact but is IN my external libraries. There some other symbols that `IntellIJ` says can't be resolved(and these are all swagger stuff) but I can still compile and run the project with `sbt`.

How is this possible? This is really annoying.

Comment: Did you reload sbt project within Idea after changing sbt structure? Or do you have auto-import enabled?

Comment: I reloaded, no auto-import.